# accessorytype of uitableview doesn't appear

Tags: iphone, ipad

I allowed selection in edit mode using

allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES ;

but at selection I want to add accessory the cell the problem is that the accessory doesn't appear

I change it in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if (self.editing) {

    NSLog(@" Editing mode  ");

     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;


}
else {
    // cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator ; 
}
```

I made sure that it enter the if statement because it display Editing mode

any suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

**editingAccessoryType**

instead of

**accessoryType**

More details at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html